# Python RE does not return anything after /ref=

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to retrieve the URL and category name from Amazon's best sellers list.  For some reason the RE I'm using stops, when it encounters `/ref=` and I truly don't see why? I'm using Python 2.7 on a Windows 7 box.

A typical record is

```html
<li><a href="http://www.amazon.ca/Best-Sellers-Appstore-Android/zgbs/mobile-apps/ref=zg_bs_nav_0">Appstore for Android</a></li>
```

and my RE is

```
Regex = "<li><a href='(http://www.amazon.ca/Best-Sellers.*?)'>(.*?)</a></li>"
Category = re.compile(Regex)
```

which return a tuple

```
[][0] http://www.amazon.ca/Best-Sellers-Appstore-Android/zgbs/mobile-apps
[][1] Appstore for Android
```

I do get all the right records but as you can see, the URL is missing `/ref=zg_bs_nav_0`.

Other levels in the category hierarchy exhibit the same issue; everything in the URL, starting with and including /ref= is missing.

Here is my code fragment after I took Martijn's suggestion

```
# First page of the list of Best Sellers categories
URL = "http://www.amazon.ca/gp/bestsellers"

# Retrieve the page source
HTMLFile = urllib.urlopen(URL)
HTMLText = HTMLFile.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(HTMLText)
for link in soup.select('li > a[href^=http://www.amazon.ca/Best-Sellers]'):
    print link['href']
    print link.get_text()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a regular expression, but matching XML with such expressions gets too complicated, too fast. Don't do that.

Use a HTML parser instead, Python has several to choose from:

- [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is part of the standard library
- [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is a popular 3rd party library
- [lxml](http://lxml.de/) is a fast and feature-rich C-based library.

The latter two also handle malformed HTML quite gracefully as well, making decent sense of many a botched website. In fact, BeautifulSoup 4 uses `lxml` under the hood as the parser of choice if it is installed.

BeautifulSoup example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlsource)
for link in soup.select('li > a[href^=http://www.amazon.ca/Best-Sellers]'):
    print link['href'], link.get_text()
```

This uses a CSS selector to find all `<a>` elements contained directly in a `<li>` element where the `href` attribute starts with the text `http://www.amazon.ca/Best-Sellers`.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> htmlsource = '<li><a href="http://www.amazon.ca/Best-Sellers-Appstore-Android/zgbs/mobile-apps/ref=zg_bs_nav_0">Appstore for Android</a></li>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlsource)
>>> for link in soup.select('li > a[href^=http://www.amazon.ca/Best-Sellers]'):
...     print link['href'], link.get_text()
... 
http://www.amazon.ca/Best-Sellers-Appstore-Android/zgbs/mobile-apps/ref=zg_bs_nav_0 Appstore for Android
```

Note that Amazon alters the response based on the headers:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> r = requests.get('http://www.amazon.ca/gp/bestsellers')
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
>>> soup.select('li > a[href^=http://www.amazon.ca/Best-Sellers]')[0]
<a href="http://www.amazon.ca/Best-Sellers-Appstore-Android/zgbs/mobile-apps">Appstore for Android</a>
>>> r = requests.get('http://www.amazon.ca/gp/bestsellers', headers={
...     'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36'})
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
>>> soup.select('li > a[href^=http://www.amazon.ca/Best-Sellers]')[0]
<a href="http://www.amazon.ca/Best-Sellers-Appstore-Android/zgbs/mobile-apps/ref=zg_bs_nav_0/185-3312534-9864113">Appstore for Android</a>
```

Comment: Hello, that was quick! I had seen someone use BeautifulSoup in a YouTube video but did not realize how much cleaner the regex is.  I guess I have some reading to do.  One thing though, I'm still not getting the /ref=... part back.

Comment: @PatrickR400: You mean when you use BeautifulSoup? Then the `<a href=".."` attribute value did not contain a `/ref` part. Perhaps those parts are added by JavaScript in the browser instead?

Comment: That is a possibility because I tried the other answer and I get nothing at all.  I do see the /ref= though in the page source returned by Firefox.

Comment: @PatrickR400: Via *view source* or the developer console? The latter shows the HTML structure *after* JavaScript has had its way. It could also mean that Amazon varies the HTML by what headers you sent to the server with the request (such as cookies, the user agent, and the `referer` (sic) header).

Comment: I do understand your point; funny things may be happening in the browser.  From the source I get "<li><a href='http://www.amazon.ca/Best-Sellers-Appstore-Android/zgbs/mobile-apps/ref=zg_bs_nav_0'>Appstore for Android</a></li>" and from the console "<li>

    <a href="http://www.amazon.ca/Best-Sellers-Appstore-Android/zgbs/mobile-apps/ref=zg_bs_nav_0">

        Appstore for Android

    </a>

</li>".  It looks the same to me except from a few spaces.

Comment: @PatrickR400: without a URL I cannot really help here, really.

Comment: Martijn, I added my code fragment to the original question.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @PatrickR400: When I set a `User-Agent` you get a response with the references.

Comment: Martijn, thanks a lot! First for the hunch that something was happening at the browser level and then for coming up with a path forward.  I'll dig into the matter.  Looks like a learning experience...

Comment: It sure was, thanks.  The solution works but it is a bit slow so I'll have to work on that.  On the other hand I won't be trying to refresh that category list that often.  Thanks again Martijn

Comment: +1 for detailed non-regex solution that gives an overview of available options. :)